# /oauth/authorization/<service> doesnt work when you click on link in browser but works when you enter it in the browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, oauth, vaadin

So I cant seem to wrap my head around this...

What could possibly the reason for this?

My settings:

Im using **Spring Boot 2.3.3** in Combination with **Vaadin 17.0.3**.
For oauth i use **Spring-Boot-Oauth2**. (Pretty much this tutorial: "https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/google-login")

It worked on Vaadin 14 but i guess after switching to Vaadin 16 something broke... Im trying to test some things, but a rollback isnt that easy for me rn.

My JDK is Java 14.

When Im trying to click on one of my OAuth Links, e.g. `"/oauth/authorization/google"` , my applicationr returns a 404. But when I enter the same link in the browser it works.

I dont know where to start, but I suspect it has to do something with Vaadins RouterLayout.

Any ideas what might cause this? I cant post code, since I dont know where the error could be...

If you need more information feel free to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `router-ignore` as an attribute on a link to make it so that the router doesn't interpret it as an internal link that should just trigger changing the view without reloading the page.

Your link could thus be something like `<a href="/oauth/authorization/google" router-ignore>Log in with Google</a>`.